# Javascript Outlook GAL

Tags: javascript, outlook, gal

Is there any way to pull data from something like a global address list in outlook through javascript(**not locally**)? An example would be to be able to search for a contact and then taking their data from the server to be stored to local variables.

Comment: Where is the JavaScript going to run? Client side in a webpage? Via node.js? Via ASP? What outlook are you talking about? The desktop Outlook application? The outlook.com website? An Exchange server?

Comment: This is in fact going to run in node.js with socket.io. And everything is on an exchange server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not locally indeed. The web browser itself has no access to this information without some sort of plugin.

What you want is an ajax call to a web server in your domain that delivers this list in json. It's up to the platform you are using to list the people in your address list.

It's possible to use the global address list ([read this](http://www.infinitec.de/post/2005/02/27/How-to-get-the-Global-Address-List-programatically.aspx)) but you probably just want to search your LDAP database.

But all of this is usually done in either ASP/C# or PHP. You can find plenty of examples to do so.